# Mongoose wrapper class. Fails in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I built a facade class for typical mongoose operations.
It seem to work well in development and testing.
When I packaged it up to be used in other development it failed.

```
//defined as
class MongooseFacade{

    constructor(name,theSchema,options){
        this._schema = theSchema;
        this._options = options||  {
                testMongooseConnect:false,
                 useMoncadeErrors:true 
                }

        this._model = mongoose.model(name,this._schema);
    }

    get model(){
        return this._model;
    }

}

// and used like:
const OrgSchema = new Schema({/* .. paths ...*/})
const OrgSchemaFacade =new MongooseFacade('OrgSchema',OrgSchema);

let theModel = OrgSchemaFacade.model();//
let theDoc = new theModel({/*...*/});//
theDoc.save((err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("Error",err);
        return err;
    }
    console.log('facade Saved *bad*')
});
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong. And more importantly - why?

Comment: What ... how with what exception it failed?

Comment: Doesn't fail. Doesn't do anything. Just hangs.  I seem to narrow it down to the 'model' or get model returns something other than expected.  However,  it looks identical(or very similar) to the return value from mongoose.model(...)  in the client code